# SQL Server : Delete the record in table based on the value of TVP table

Tags: sql-server

I have a **PurchaseStationeryDetails** and **TVP(Table valued parameter) TVP_PurchaseStationeryDetails**, My question is-->I wanted to **delete** the record from **PurchaseStationeryDetails** that are not avaliable in **TVP table**. [image]

```
declare @TVP_PurchaseStationeryDetails as TVP_PurchaseStationeryDetails
```

Just Consider that i inserted data into **TVP table**

```
DELETE  from PurchaseStationeryDetails
            WHERE PurchaseStationeryMasterId = 1003 AND  PurchaseStationeryDetailsId  IN
                    (SELECT PSD.PurchaseStationeryDetailsId FROM PurchaseStationeryDetails PSD, @TVP_PurchaseStationeryDetails TVP_PSD 
                           WHERE PSD.PurchaseStationeryMasterId = TVP_PSD.PurchaseStationeryMasterId AND PSD.PurchaseStationeryDetailsId  ! = TVP_PSD.PurchaseStationeryDetailsId AND TVP_PSD.PurchaseStationeryDetailsId != 0)
```

**Columns** in **PurchaseStationeryDetails**--->PurchaseStationeryDetailsId, PurchaseStationeryMasterId.....etc

**Columns** in **TVP_PurchaseStationeryDetails**--->PurchaseStationeryDetailsId, PurchaseStationeryMasterId.....etc

Here i wanted to delete the record -> **104,2** from PurchaseStationeryDetails table

Comment: Did I miss the question? "that are **not** available in TVP table"... Maybe just `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` ?

Comment: you didn't specify the question

Comment: @Shnugo ok i will try that NOT In and reply you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try smth like this**

```
delete from PSD

from PurchaseStationeryDetails PSD
where not exists ( 
                  select 1 from  @TVP_PurchaseStationeryDetails TVP_PSD
                  where PSD.PurchaseStationeryMasterId = TVP_PSD.PurchaseStationeryMasterId
                  and isnull(PSD.PurchaseStationeryDetailsId,0)  = TVP_PSD.PurchaseStationeryDetailsId 
                  )

and PSD.PurchaseStationeryMasterId = 1003
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `Left` or `Right Outer Join`

```
 create table #tvp (id int, val int)

insert into #tvp 
values
(101, 1), (102,  2),(103,2)

create table #purchase (iden int, value int)

insert into #purchase 
values
(101, 1), (102,  2),(103,2),(104,2)


delete p
from #tvp t
right outer join
#purchase p 
on (t.val = p.value and t.id = p.iden)
where t.id is null
```